# add user input data to consts in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have an *app.js* file in a trello clone.

Toy data is stored,representing posts.

```
const book1 = [
    {id: uuid(), content: 'reflections'}
];
const book2 = [
    {id: uuid(), content: 'arising'},
]
```

a single constant pulls the toy data into columns for the trello clone.

```
const clusterColumns =
    {
        [uuid()]: {
            name: 'Book 1',
            items: book1
        },
        [uuid()]: {
            name: 'Book 2',
            items: book2
        },
    };
```

The data is hard coded into these consts. Id like to add a user input to the page that, so that users can *add their own items to consts for the trello clone*.

the clusterColumns const is added to a third const that simply cleans up the data as i move it around on the board:

```
const onDragEnd = (result, columns, setColumns ) => {
    if(!result.destination ) return;
    const {source, destination} = result;
    if (source.droppableId!==destination.droppableId) {
        const sourceColumn = columns[source.droppableId];
        const destColumn = columns[destination.droppableId];
        const sourceItems = [...sourceColumn.items];
        const destItems = [...destColumn.items];
        const [removed] = sourceItems.splice(source.index, 1);
        destItems.splice(destination.index, 0, removed);
        setColumns({
            ...columns,
            [source.droppableId]:{
                ...sourceColumn,
                items: sourceItems,
            },
            [destination.droppableId]:{
                ...destColumn,
                items: destItems
            }
        })
    }
    else {
        const column = columns[source.droppableId];
        const copiedItems = [...column.items];
        const [removed] = copiedItems.splice(source.index, 1);
        copiedItems.splice(destination.index, 0, removed)
        setColumns({
            ...columns,
            [source.droppableId]: {
                ...column,
                items: copiedItems
            }
        })
    }
};
```

a main bit of the *app.js* file is a nested function that builds drag and drop elements with some style, pulling in the toy data

```
function App() {
    const [columns, setColumns] = useState(clusterColumns);
    return (
        <div>
            <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'left', height: '95%', position: "relative",
                top: 5, left: 90, opacity: '27%'}}>
                <DragDropContext onDragEnd={result => onDragEnd(result, columns, setColumns)}>
                    {Object.entries(columns).map(([id, column]) => {
                        return (
                            <div style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column', alignItems:'center',
                                fontFamily: 'Montez, sans-serif', color: '#913aff', fontSize: 27, padding:5, borderRadius: '19px',
                            }}><h2  style={{fontSize:(19*3), height: 45}}>{column.name}</h2>
                                <h2  style={{fontSize:(19*3), height: 45, top:'9px', position:'absolute', opacity:'60%', color:'#ffa0f9'}}>{column.name}</h2>
                                <div style={{margin: 2}}>
                                    <Droppable droppableId={id} key={id} >
                                        {(provided, snapshot) => {
                                            return (
                                                <div {...provided.droppableProps}
                                                     ref={provided.innerRef}
                                                     style={{
                                                         padding: 9,
                                                         width: 190,
                                                         minHeight: 9,
                                                         opacity: '95%',
                                                         borderRadius: '9px',
                                                         background: 'linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(196, 181, 255, 1), rgba(132,47,0,0.27)'}} >
                                                         {column.items.map((item, index) => {
                                                            return (
                                                                <Draggable key={item.id} draggableId={item.id} index={index}>
                                                                    {(provided, snapshot) => {
                                                                        return (
                                                                            <div
                                                                                ref={provided.innerRef}
                                                                                {...provided.draggableProps}
                                                                                {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                                                                                style={{
                                                                                    opacity: '95%',
                                                                                    userSelect: 'none',
                                                                                    padding: 19,
                                                                                    margin: '0px 0px 3px 0px',
                                                                                    backgroundColor: snapshot.isDragging ? '#54ffff':'#b3f542',
                                                                                    background: 'linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba(84, 255, 255, 0.63), rgba(179, 245, 66, 0.81)',
                                                                                    color: 'rgb(115,38,0)' ,
                                                                                    fontFamily: 'Montez',
                                                                                    fontSize: 36,
                                                                                    borderRadius: '9px',
                                                                                    ...provided.draggableProps.style
                                                                                }}>
                                                                                {item.content}
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        )
                                                                    }}
                                                                </Draggable>
                                                            )
                                                        }
                                                    )}
                                                    {provided.placeholder}
                                                </div>
                                            )
                                        }}
                                    </Droppable>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </DragDropContext>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I've tried adding another class:

```
class Cell extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <form>

                <input
                    type="text" style={{
                        display:'flex',
                    position:'relative',
                        top: '-360px',
                    right:'95px',
                    fontFamily: "VT323",
                    width:'144px',
                    fontSize:'36px',
                    color: 'rgb(115,38,0)',
                    opacity:'60%',
                    borderRadius: '9px',
                    height: '45px',
                    background: 'radial-gradient(rgba(196, 181, 255, .9), rgba(168,255,0,0.19)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)'
                }}
                />
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

But it is a simple user form. I'd like to have the data entered be added to those consts at the top of the program.

Comment: What do you mean by Trello clone? Trello seems to be an app but not an open source one. Are you trying to recreate it? It would help if you either linked to the repo that you cloned or post some of the code you've written to try what you're asking.

Comment: sure, will edit this to include the whole program  in a sec